# How do I flag a comment for moderator attention?

Tags: support, offensive, flags

I don't appreciate [this kind of vulgar behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23737420/3198973). How can I flag this comment for moderator attention?

Comment: click the flag icon next to the comment

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365 ; the flag icon is right under the upvote icon, to the left of the comment

Comment: I don't see it from my mobile. Maybe that's why? Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the flag link, choosing the "offensive" option in the resulting dialog. In a mobile browser, the flag and upvote links may be revealed by first tapping on the body of the comment.

> [image]

More information can be found at [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/) on Meta.SE. In particular, if a comment is flagged as "offensive" by enough users, it will be deleted without a moderator even needing to be involved (I believe that this happened here).

Comment: Thanks. That appears to be unavailable on chrome for iOS. Will put in a feature request later.

Comment: I don't use Chrome, but try tapping the body of the comment itself to reveal the links. That's how it works in iOS Safari.

Comment: Also, if you want a moderator to step in and have some words with the user leaving such a comment (like I just did in this case), feel free to leave us an "other" flag on the post where the comment occurred and let us know that there's some abusive behavior going on in the comments.

Comment: Hugging a child like a what???

Comment: @Will I'm no prude, but I won't go into the details of it. It wasn't originally "hugging"... and that's all I'll say.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks. Will do if I ever run into something like this again. I just couldn't flag it from my mobile is all.