# Add ability to flag comments to mobile version of site

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, flags

I discovered earlier [that we cannot flag offensive comments from the mobile version](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255443/how-do-i-flag-a-comment-for-moderator-attention) of the site. You can flag comments by switching to the full site, but this definitely took some figuring out.

We should be able to easily flag offensive material regardless which version of the site we're using.

Comment: Agreed. I'm fairly certain we used to have this option.

Comment: The question is two years old and you can **still not flag comments on mobile version!**

Comment: Well almost 4 years old now and still nothing happened

Comment: Bumping this question because flagging has become the primary functionality of SO.

Comment: @AndrasDeak flagging your comment as noise but lucky for you I am on mobile. I'll try again in 6 to 8 weeks...

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to full site mode (which is responsive now on Stack Overflow and [some other sites in the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314979/295232)) with a link in the footer. That mode is eventually going to replace the mobile web version we currently have; any new developments on the current mobile version are unlikely.

In the full site mode, the gray flags works just like they would on your computer.

[image]

<sub>the question / comments above were randomly chosen, I haven't flagged anything</sub>

Comment: Too bad the responsive desktop site is ugly as sin on mobile.