# Mobile version of website URL

Tags: feature-request

The mobile version of the website does not contain the full functionality of the desktop website (e.g. this [Add ability to flag comments to mobile version of site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255458/add-ability-to-flag-comments-to-mobile-version-of-site) is missing as well as some other things), and it's just fine: I use a switcher on the bottom of the page (in the footer) to switch to the desktop version. My problem is that after I am done, it is unbelieavably hard to switch back to mobile because the `full-site` link is placed on a totally different location and although I know it is *there* I'm spending ages to find it.

Could this be somehow improved? E.g. Github has a really good and comfortable implementation of switching back from desktop to mobile: the link is huge and located on the top of the page.

Comment: Well, they used to be in pretty much the same spot; new footer just hasn't made it to mobile yet.